# Use ENUM in array of objects

Tags: postgresql, json, array

Is it possible to setup an ARRAY column with objects/JSON on a TABLE, forcing a parameter of the objects in the ARRAY to adhere to an ENUM, while keeping that object parameter unique?

Data examples:

ENUM val1, val2, val3

```
[{p1: val1, p2: 'something'}, {p1: val2, p2: 'something'}] <-- valid
[{p1: val1, p2: 'something'}, {p1: val4, p2: 'something'}] <-- not valid, val4 not an ENUM value
[{p1: val1, p2: 'something'}, {p1: val1, p2: 'something else'}] <-- not valid, p1 not unique
```

If it is possible, using PostgreSQL and sequelize, how would I go about it, setting up the column?

Comment: Use a table, enforce the constraints there and convert the table contents to json?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options,

1. You can just use `CHECK` conditions if it's on one table's jsonb column
2. `CREATE TABLE` with the possible values and set it as an fkey.
3. Reduce that jsonb to something more logical in the app, or in the db. Create a function such that `f(jsonb)=>k` and store k on the table, or possibly as an `ENUM`